# Testing String Exists Regardless of Capitalization, Python

Tags: python, string

I have:

```
x = []
x.append("ds")
```

I want to check that "ds" is in x, but I don't care is it is capitalized or not. So if I want to run

```
if "DS" in x:
    print "Yes"
```

I want "Yes" to return. I just want to make sure that the string "ds" is in x, regardless of whether or not it is capitalized. How do I do this? I've been through the list of [string methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods), but I can't seem to find something simple that does this, just a combination of testing different letter cases, which can be cumbersome.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if any(s.lower() == "ds" for s in x):
    print "Yes"
```

Of course you could also use `s.upper() == "DS"`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was using upper and lower incorrectly. I have something that works now after seeing this. Thanks @F.J

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> 'DS'.lower()
'ds'
```

Comment: `x` is a list, through which the OP wants to do a case-insensitive search.

Comment: true, but it looked to me that the major issue he had was that he couldn't find the lower function

Comment: Is was more like I wanted to check a list of string values and that contained 'ds' in that list, then I wanted to return all the values (i.e. is x contained ['ds', 'Ds', 'dS', 'DS'], I wanted all values to return, regardless of capitalization. I don't think I worded my question clearly enough. My apologies.